# Mailgun settings Outlook for mac client

Tags: macos, outlook, smtp, mailgun

I am trying to connect Outlook for Mac version 16.25 to an SMTP user account on mailgun.

I am using the IMAP/POP account type and have entered in my credentials for the SMTP user as directed by mailgun.

Regardless of the port settings, I get "unable to sign in, check credentials and try again" error.

Can outlook for the mac make this connection?

If so, can someone share the correct incoming and outgoing servers configurations?